# Flat space current conservation sign confusion

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, metric-tensor, special-relativity

It is said that in Minkowski spacetime, the current conservation law for the number current $N^\mu$ where $N^0$ is the number density and $N^i, i=1,2,3$  is the particle flux in the $x^i $ direction, is given by

$$\partial_\mu N^\mu=0 ....................(*)$$

What I don't understand is he following.

I would have thought that $$\partial_t N^0=-\nabla\cdot \vec N$$ where $\vec N$ has components $N^i, i=1,2,3$.

But using the Minkowski metric, $(*)$ reads
$$\partial_t N^0=\nabla\cdot \vec N$$

Why is there not a minus sign on the RHS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are getting confused with the notation. Notice that $$ \partial_\mu N^\mu \equiv \partial_0 N^0 +\nabla\cdot\vec{N},$$ where $\nabla\cdot\vec{N} \equiv \partial_iN^i$. Now, another way o writting this expression is: $$\partial_\mu N^\mu = \eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu N_\nu=\partial_0 N_0 - \partial_i N_i.$$ Vectors are tensor with only one contravariant indice, i.e. upstairs. Vectors and covectors are related through the metric by $$v^\mu =\eta^{\mu\nu}v_\nu \Leftrightarrow \{v^0,v^i\}=\{v_0,-v_i\},$$where I assumed $\eta_{\mu\nu}=(1,-1,-1,-1)$.